# Could not find devise mapping for path "/". before the user has signed in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am getting the following error when i go to `root` after logging in

```
    Could not find devise mapping for path "/". 

This may happen for two reasons: 

1) You forgot to wrap your route inside the scope block. For example: devise_scope :user do get "/some/route" => "some_devise_controller" end 

2) You are testing a Devise controller bypassing the router. If so, you can explicitly tell Devise which mapping to use: @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
```

**Routes File**

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do

      root 'pages#home'

      devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: "users/sessions", registrations: "users/registrations", confirmations: "users/confirmations", passwords: "users/passwords" }, :skip => [:sessions]
  as :user do
    get 'sign_in' => 'users/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
    post 'sign_in' => 'users/sessions#create', :as => :user_session
    match 'sign_out' => 'users/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session,
      :via => Devise.mappings[:user].sign_out_via
  end

    end
```

Even though i have a `route_path` it throws up the error.

Comment: As the error says, try wrapping your routes under `devise_scope :user`

Comment: @Pavan if the user is not signed in? then why does it need to be scoped inside the `:user`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try writing routes in scope block.

```
devise_scope :user do
    # write all your routes inside this block
end
```

You can find more about scope here

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes

Comment: why does it nee to be inside the user scope?

Comment: You can check this
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes